# Processing Cube with datasource on another server

Tags: sql-server, ssas, xmla

I have a Cube which is hosted on Server1.

Then, in SSMS I do this: Right click -> Script Database As -> Create to -> New Query Editor Window. Then copy resulted XMLA. Then open XMLS query window on Server2, paste, run. Cube copied.

I right click Cube on SSMS and click process. Here is the error:

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ; 08001.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly related to the Datasource settings (in the SSAS database).  If you look at its Properties (double-click), there's an *Impersonation Info* setting under *Security Settings*.

The most robust setting here is "Impersonate", where you specify a user that will be used to access the source data for the cube (which may be anywhere the Datasource points).  If you have "Use Current User" set here, SSAS will attempt to connect to the datasource as you (how ever you are logged in to the SSAS server).

This user (you) may not have the necessary permissions to access the source data.  Or there may be network-related security set up that prevents the SSAS service (or anything) on Server 2 from talking to the server that hosts the source data.